# flash player it is supported on the emulator

Tags: android

I want to install the flash player into the emulator. It's possible??

Answer (score 1):

The Flash plugin will not run on the emulator for multiple technical reasons: no ARMv7 emulation, and no hardware OpenGL ES 2.0 emulation yet.